# Overfitting in Gradient Boosting

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, boosting, unbalanced-classes, overfitting

I have a very unbalanced dataset(99.8% negative,0.2% positive) with approximately 60 variables. I removed somewhere around 40 variables based on the variance inflation factor. Then I used SMOTE to oversample the minority data.

I am now using XGBoost to prepare a model. I have tried class weighting, regularization and adjusting variables using Randomized Search CV for other parameters. 
However my model still  massively overfits, F1 score is approx 0.5 , which precision and recall both being dramatically reduced.
How do I reduce overfitting in this scenario?

Comment: [Our Stephan Kolassa argues that class imbalance presents no problem at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) // Are you sure you have overfitting and not just poor performance? How does your training performance compare to your out-of-sample performance?

Comment: How many total positive cases do you have?

Comment: 5934 samples, 111 are positive. Precision, Recall , ROC AUC, F1 Score all are 1.0 for training data. This is an overfitting issue